Differences Between Modified Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Van der Waerden Tests
I am trying to understand the differences between the Modified Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and the Van der Waerden test. I am new to this and struggling to grasp their distinct features. Specifically, what is "modified" in the Modified Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?
Thank you very much in advance.

There are many ways to "modify" the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, so the "Modified Kolmogorov-Smirnov test" is not a well-defined phrase. Can you cite the source where you've read about it?

Specifically the regular Kolmogorov test is a two-sided test for the hypothesis that the c.d.f. of two distributions are equal, the Smirnov test is a one-sided test for the same hypothesis, and the Van der Waerden test tests whether or not the c.d.f. of $k$ distributions are equal. (So the main difference is the $2$ vs. the $k$.)

@daniel-p
Can you please explain in more layman's terms, and more detail? Thank you in advance.
